Why does using image_url in one part of my Shopify Liquid code cause a 404 error, but not in others?
I'm building a custom section in Shopify that includes an image modal for displaying product images. The issue I'm facing is that when I use image_url for the src attribute in one part of my code, I get a 404 warning in the console, while it works fine in other parts of my code.
Code that gives a 404 warning:
<!-- Product Modal -->
<a id="product-modal" class="product-modal" href="" target="_self">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <img id="modal-product-image" src="{{ product.featured_image | image_url: width: 500, height: 500 }}" alt="Product Image" class="modal-product-image" width="500" height="500">
    <h3 id="modal-product-name" class="modal-product-name"></h3>
    <p id="modal-product-price" class="modal-product-price"></p>
    <button id="close-modal" class="close-modal">×</button>
  </div>
</a>

Code that works (but is flagged as outdated):
<!-- Product Modal -->
<a id="product-modal" class="product-modal" href="" target="_self">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <img id="modal-product-image" src="" alt="Product Image" class="modal-product-image" width="500" height="500">
    <h3 id="modal-product-name" class="modal-product-name"></h3>
    <p id="modal-product-price" class="modal-product-price"></p>
    <button id="close-modal" class="close-modal">×</button>
  </div>
</a>

I've tried:

Using img_url instead, which successfully generates the image URL but gets flagged by Shopify's theme check as outdated and not best practice.
Ensuring product.featured_image is present and valid in the current context to confirm that the image source is correctly referenced.
Using image_url throughout my code, where it works correctly in other parts of the template but causes a 404 warning specifically when used in the src attribute of the modal image.
Using <img id="modal-product-image" src="" ...>, which avoids the 404 warning but gets flagged as not best practice due to an empty src attribute.

My Question: Why does using image_url work in other parts of my code but causes a 404 warning when used in the modal's src attribute? How can I fix this while adhering to Shopify's best practices?

What does the actually resulting URL in the src attribute look like? Is it an absolute URL, or a relative one? And if the latter, is it root-relative (starts with a leading slash), or not?

Hi @C3roe , this is the error I get in the console when I use image_url for the src attribute inside the modal:
GET https://lookbook-feature-demo-store.myshopify.com/Liquid%20error%20(sections/lookbook-hotspot%20line%2091):%20invalid%20url%20input 404 (Not Found)
I believe image_url should generate an absolute URL, so I’m not sure why it’s causing this error here specifically. The issue doesn’t occur with other image_url instances in my code, just in this particular modal context.

"Liquid error (sections/lookbook-hotspot line 91): invalid url input" - have you made a debug output of the value, to see what it actually is?

You need to check the product have the featured_image set or not.

{% if product.featured_image != blank %}
// code here.
{% endif %}

